# JQuery Empty A Textfield When I click in it

Tags: javascript, jquery, textfield, erase, string

How do I empty a textfield (html form) if I click in it to write something.

Pseudo Code:

```
On click #searchform
Erase String in #searchform
```

Comment: Why do you want to do that? What if you typed something wrong and just want to edit? It seems that what you want is that if the textfield contains the original text(like: Enter a search term), then it should be removed when you click. Right?

Comment: @tbleckert Indeed. I think thats a standard usabillity thing.. so I need a conditional branch so that the user doesnt get pissed of..

Comment: Why don't you use the HTML 5 placeholder attribute?!

Comment: @Pavel Nikolov I doesnt know that the W3C has thought about something this.

Comment: the placeholder attribute is the way to go! Here is and article about it http://davidwalsh.name/html5-placeholder and here is the demo http://davidwalsh.name/dw-content/html5-placeholder.php you can take a look at my answer to see how to make the placeholder attribute work for older browsers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Try it here](http://jsfiddle.net/pmsGB/)

```
$('#searchform').click(function() { 
    if ($(this).val() == 'Enter search term') {   
        $(this).data('original', $(this).val()).val('');
    }
});

$('#searchform').blur(function() { 
    if ($(this).val() == '') {   
        $(this).val($(this).data('original'));
    }
});
```

**EDIT** As of now you should use the [placeholder](http://diveintohtml5.info/forms.html#placeholder) attribute and if you want, use the above as a polyfill for missing placeholder support.

```
if (!('placeholder' in document.createElement('input'))){
    $('input[placeholder]').each(function() {
        $(this).placeholder();
    });
}
```

And turn the original code into a plugin for easy use (with some small mods).

```
jQuery.fn.placeholder = function() {
    return this.each(function() {
        var value = $(this).attr('placeholder');
        jQuery(this).val(value).addClass('placeholder');
        jQuery(this).focus(function() {
            if (jQuery(this).val() == value) {
                jQuery(this).val('').removeClass('placeholder');
            }
        });

        jQuery(this).blur(function() {
            if (jQuery(this).val() == '') {
                jQuery(this).val(value).addClass('placeholder');
            }
        });
    });
};
```

Comment: It is harder to add validation this way. Imagine the field is required. Then the required field validator has to exclude the initial value. Also imagine that you would like to use different font for the placeholder (or at least different color) - then you would have to toggleClasses. I think `placeholder` attribute is the way to go.

Comment: Well yes, but this was in 2010, when placeholders wasn't super known and well implemented in the browsers. Of course, it's another time now. But I should update my answer.

Answer (score 5):

```
$('#searchform').click(function() { $(this).val('') })
```

Answer (score 3):

I'd recommend you using the HTML5 placeholder attribute. For example:

```
<input type="text" placeholder="some default string if empty" />
```

This will work with most of the newest browsers and for older ones there is a workaround jQuery plugin. Here is the link to the [placeholder plugin](https://github.com/miketaylr/jQuery-html5-placeholder).

And then you simply call:

```
$('input[placeholder]').placeholder();
```

Comment: The placeholder demo http://davidwalsh.name/dw-content/html5-placeholder.php does not work in FF 3.5 - I dont want to use an extra plugin for this.. well I choose tbleckert's answer..

Comment: @Tomkay Now the placeholder is the recommended way of doing things. You can detect if the browser supports it with Modernizr or just with a simple javascript if. I think now only IE <= 8 would use a polyfill.

Comment: Yeah, I guess HTML5 is popular enough now to do the job. I use the browser validation on new projects as well.

Answer (score 1):

If you are wanting to clear a default value from a field such as *"Enter Search Term"* I use the following code:

```
function clearText(thefield){
if (thefield.defaultValue==thefield.value)
thefield.value = ""
}
```

and then on my input field I add:

```
onfocus="clearText(this)"
```

So it would be:

```
<input type="text" name="username" value="enter your name here"  onfocus="clearText(this)">
```

Comment: Pretty new to the scripting side of things so any pointers would be greatly received as to why I shouldn't. Was just sharing the solution I've used in the past to get around this problem.

Comment: Thank you for your affort Vince. : ) Im sure this work fine but the code can be compressed in some way.

Comment: I'm sorry. The reason I don't like inline js, or inline css for that matter is that I want the HTML to be as clean as possible. Semantics is king!